# ActiveRecord Time Comparisons in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, time

I am trying to write some scopes that are meant to pull events for future, past, and current events from my sqlite database. Here are the scopes I have set in my Event model with their accompanying predicate methods:

```
  scope :upcoming, where("start_at >= :time", time: Time.current ).order('start_at asc')
  scope :recent, where("end_at <= :time", time: Time.current ).order('end_at desc')
  scope :current, where("start_at <= :time AND end_at >= :time", time: Time.current ).order('start_at asc')



  def upcoming?
    start_at.future?
  end

  def recent?
    end_at.past?
  end

  def current?
    end_at.future? && start_at.past?
  end
```

And here are the results I'm getting from my rspec tests

```
  is in the future
    should be upcoming
    should not be recent
    should not be current
    should be in upcoming
    should not be in recent (FAILED - 1)
    should not be in current (FAILED - 2)
  is in the past
    should not be upcoming
    should be recent
    should not be current
    should not be in upcoming
    should be in recent (FAILED - 3)
    should not be in current
  is happening now
    should not be upcoming
    should not be recent
    should be current
    should not be in upcoming
    should not be in recent
    should be in current (FAILED - 4)
```

As you can see the predicate method tests run fine once the dates are pulled from the database, but when actually querying the database things go haywire.

Here is the rspec I'm running to test it(I'm a little bit new to it, so there might be some issues here, but I have seen the scopes failing with manual testing as well):

```
  let(:future) { Event.create(start_at: start_time, end_at: end_time ) }
  let(:past) { Event.create(start_at: start_time, end_at: end_time ) }
  let(:happening) { Event.create(start_at: start_time, end_at: end_time ) }

  context "#upcoming?" do
    it { should respond_to(:upcoming?) }
  end
  context "#recent?" do
    it { should respond_to(:recent?) }
  end
  context "#current?" do
    it { should respond_to(:current?) }
  end

  context "is in the future" do
    subject(:event) { future }
    let(:start_time) { Time.now + 1.minute }
    let(:end_time) { Time.now + 1.minute + 1.second }
    it { should be_upcoming }
    it { should_not be_recent }
    it { should_not be_current }
    it "should be in upcoming" do
      Event.upcoming.should include(event)
    end
    it "should not be in recent" do
      Event.upcoming.should_not include(event)
    end
    it "should not be in current" do
      Event.upcoming.should_not include(event)
    end
  end

  context "is in the past" do
    subject(:event) { past }
    let(:start_time) { Time.now - 1.minute }
    let(:end_time) { Time.now - 1.minute + 1.second }
    it { should_not be_upcoming }
    it { should be_recent }
    it { should_not be_current }
    it "should not be in upcoming" do
      Event.upcoming.should_not include(event)
    end
    it "should be in recent" do
      Event.upcoming.should include(event)
    end
    it "should not be in current" do
      Event.upcoming.should_not include(event)
    end
  end

  context "is happening now" do
    subject(:event) { happening }
    let(:start_time) { Time.now - 1.minute }
    let(:end_time) { Time.now + 1.minute }
    it { should_not be_upcoming }
    it { should_not be_recent }
    it { should be_current }
    it "should not be in upcoming" do
      Event.upcoming.should_not include(event)
    end
    it "should not be in recent" do
      Event.upcoming.should_not include(event)
    end
    it "should be in current" do
      Event.upcoming.should include(event)
    end
  end
```

Any idea on what's going wrong? I've tried several variants of `Time.current` And they all produce similar results.

Comment: First off: make your scopes via lambdas. Your way some `Time.current` will be fetched once and will persist for all the time the program runs, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: What jdoe said. it's probably an issue with the time being fetched once.

Comment: I've tried that before and it actually comes out with more errors. But I see how the lambda couldn't possibly be a bad thing, so I'll update the code and tests in the question.

Comment: You have to use lambdas this way: `scope :upcoming, lambda { where... }`.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that now and I'm back to where I started with the original failures :(

Comment: @jdoe Ok, I've actually done some manual tests now, and everything seems to be working, so it must be an issue with the rspec now. If you post your answer I'll accept it. If you know what's wrong with the rspec feel free to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @jdoe says in his comment, you have to use a lambda to avoid Time.current being fetched only once.